# Closed Form Addition of BCD numbers

Tags: logic, arithmetic, binary, decimal-expansion

Binary Coded Decimal (BCD) number representation is a 4-bit encoding which maps numbers 0-9 to their counterpart binary codes. Addition of BCD numbers can be formulated as follows:

- z = a + b (If z < 10)
- z = a + b - 10 (If z >= 10)

For instance, If we add 7 (0111) and 8 (1000), we get 15-10=5, and a carry for a higher order. My question: How can we formulate the aforementioned formula without comparison operator; i.e. what is a closed form formula for addition of 2 BCD numbers (like for example z = a+b-3ab+64a^2-128b^3, this is just an example form of what I need)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will be an enormous expression but you can do it.  If we note that $z=7$ when $a=4$ and $b=3$ we can have a term on the right that is $a(a-1)(a-2)(a-3)(a-5)\ldots (a-9)b(b-1)(b-2)(b-4)\ldots (b-9)$ divided by a constant.  The point is that this term is $0$ unless $a=4,b=3$ and we choose the constant to make the product $7$ when $a=4,b=3$.  Another $99$ terms will get the job done.  If you write it out, you can feed it to a computer algebra package to expand and collect terms for you.

Comment: Good idea, but this leads to real coefficients. I can only use integer coefficients or powers of 2 and 10 (positive or negative). Do you have any more idea what we can do?

Comment: They are rational, so you can store them as numerator and denominator.  They will be around $9!^2$ so too large for $32$ bit integers

Comment: @msj: be aware that this answer is more in the spirit of an elaborate joke than an attempt to be helpful :-/